# Having issue when there are identical keys in nodeset formed

Tags: xslt-1.0

My input xml is as below, I am facing issue when there are multiple identical keys present in a nodeset, its not forming proper output structure. I am using keys to form the nodeset by using ref attribute. I am making use of these `<SL id="L1S1">` and `<pit ref="L1S1">` to form nodesets. Id attribute of SL node(i.e `<SL id="L1S1">`) is formed using "L1" in `<L Id="L1">`. Also ref attribute of pit node(i.e `<pit ref="L1S1">`) is formed using "L1" in `<L Id="L1">`.

This solution works fine if I do not have multiple pit nodes with same reference number. I am using xslt1.0, and I have issue when multiple identical keys are found in nodeset.

```
Input xml as below
```

```xml
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <test>ed</test>
    <SL id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
    </SL>
    <SL id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
    </SL>
  </L>
  <cp>
    <current>
      <Amt>20154.00</Amt>
    </current>
    <pi>
      <pit ref="L1S1">
        <value>123</value>
      </pit>
      <pit ref="L1S1">
        <value>234</value>
      </pit>
      <pit ref="L1S2">
        <value>1232</value>
      </pit>
    </pi>
  </cp>
</root>
```

Expected output should be:

```xml
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <SL id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
    </SL>
    <pit ref="L1S1">
      <value>123</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
  <L Id="L1">
    <SL id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
    </SL>
    <pit ref="L1S1">
      <value>234</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
  <L Id="L1">
    <SL id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
    </SL>
    <pit ref="L1S2">
      <value>1232</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
</root>
```

```xml
  <xsl:key name="pit-SL" match="pit" use="@ref" />
  <xsl:key name="pit-L"  match="pit" use="substring(@ref,1,2)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="L[SL]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SL"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SL">
    <L>
      <xsl:copy-of select="parent::L/@Id"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of  select="@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('pit-SL',@id)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </L>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="L[not(SL)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pit-L',@Id)">
      <xsl:with-param name="L" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pit">
    <xsl:param name="L"/>
    <L>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$L/@Id"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </L>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="pit" match="pit" use="@ref" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="L">
            <xsl:variable name="Id" select="@Id" />
            <xsl:for-each select="SL">
                <xsl:variable name="SL" select="." />
                <xsl:for-each select="key('pit', @id)">
                    <L>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$Id"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$SL"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </L>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```