# Not able to get details of current node in template match 'L'

Tags: xslt-1.0

This xslt works perfectly fine but i need to get additional details under L node in the output generated, I am having issue forming test, testone nodes. The solution i tried is `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|SL[@id = $ref]" mode="Loutput"/>` including node() in this line but  output will be wrong in this case.

Input xml as below

```xml
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <test>ed</test>
    <testone><testtwo>ed</testtwo></testone>    
    <SL id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
    <SL id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
  </L>
  <cp>
    <current>
      <Amt>20154.00</Amt>
    </current>
    <pi>
      <pit ref="L1S1">
        <value>123</value>
      </pit>
      <pit ref="L1S2">
        <value>1232</value>
      </pit>
    </pi>
  </cp>
</root>
```

Expected output should be:

```xml
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <test>ed</test>
    <testone><testtwo>ed</testtwo></testone>    
    <SL id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
    <pit ref="L1S1">
      <value>123</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
  <L Id="L1">
    <test>ed</test>
    <testone><testtwo>ed</testtwo></testone>    
    <SL id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
    <pit ref="L1S2">
      <value>1232</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
</root>
```

This xslt works fine with all my scenarios.

```xml
    <xsl:key name="SLkey" match="SL" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="pitKey" match="pit" use="generate-id()"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|.//pit"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="pit">
      <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Is there an SL node match?  -->
        <xsl:when test="key('SLkey', @ref)[1]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('SLkey', @ref)[1]/.." mode="Loutput">
            <xsl:with-param name="ref" select="@ref"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pitID" select="generate-id(.)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- Use the first L in the document. -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//L[1]" mode="Loutput">
            <xsl:with-param name="ref" select="@ref"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pitID" select="generate-id(.)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <!--  **********************  -->
    <!--   Loutput mode templates  -->
    <!--  **********************  -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="Loutput">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="Loutput"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="L" mode="Loutput">
      <xsl:param name="ref"/>
      <xsl:param name="pitID"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|SL[@id = $ref]" mode="Loutput"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pitKey', $pitID)" mode="Loutput"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: BTW:  For some reason I don't see the keys in the above code.  You may want to add them to help other people answer your question.

Comment: I dont want to add new elements, I want to copy contents under L node to generated output for ex test and testone nodes under L.

Comment: Check the new answer.  This should give you what you want.   Your attempt was close.  You just needed to filter node().

Comment: Thanks for encouraging me. I am getting the exception XslTransformException --------------------- Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added, Also I could see some of my scenarios failing with this

Comment: Original link for this question can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871953/issue-in-forming-node-structure-when-multiple-identical-keys-found-in-a-nodeset

Comment: I just reran the code I posted.  It works for me.  Did you copy out all of code and run it on you end?  At a minimum do overwrite the entire <xsl:template match="L" mode="Loutput"> template.

Comment: It seems the problem is you are applying templates to nodes before attributes.  Make sure the attributes are in the first apply templates.  (The don't necessarily have to be in the first position in the select of the apply templates.

Comment: I did copy, but im not getting desired output for all scenarios mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871953/issue-in-forming-node-structure-when-multiple-identical-keys-found-in-a-nodeset

Comment: It's the same code with the modification you requested here.  I suggest going back to the code that was working for you and working forward from there.  I've shown you what you need to do to get the other L child nodes in your output...  good luck!

Comment: hmm, I had messed up the code, It works, Sorry to bother you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

```
<xsl:key name="SLkey" match="SL" use="@id"/>
<xsl:key name="pitKey" match="pit" use="generate-id()"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|.//pit"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pit">
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- Is there an SL node match?  -->
    <xsl:when test="key('SLkey', @ref)[1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('SLkey', @ref)[1]/.." mode="Loutput">
        <xsl:with-param name="ref" select="@ref"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pitID" select="generate-id(.)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:when>
    <!-- Use the first L in the document. -->
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//L[1]" mode="Loutput">
        <xsl:with-param name="ref" select="@ref"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pitID" select="generate-id(.)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--  **********************  -->
<!--   Loutput mode templates  -->
<!--  **********************  -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="Loutput">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="Loutput"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="L" mode="Loutput">
  <xsl:param name="ref"/>
  <xsl:param name="pitID"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[local-name() != 'SL']" mode="Loutput"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SL[@id = $ref]" mode="Loutput"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pitKey', $pitID)" mode="Loutput"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```